# Positioning when parent isn't position: relative

Tags: html, css

I have a button inside of a parent div.  I would like the button to be in the upper-right of the div.

If the parent div had its CSS `position` set to `relative`, I would just make the button's `position: absolute` and `top: 0px` and `right: 0px` or something along those lines (right would actually be dynamically based on the size of the button).

The problem is, someone else made the div, it has no position attribute, and I can't change its style.  How can I still position this button where I want it?

Example HTML:

```
<div id="someone_elses_div">
  <button id="my_button">Hello World</button>
</div>
```

Comment: post the relevant html please

Comment: So just put it as the first element in the div, and then float:right? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @djbhindi, that does work, but I will not always have the option of making my element the first in the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the css `calc()` to calculate left margin for the button according the the div's width: <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/ELbvN/)</kbd>

as you can see, almost all current browsers support `calc()`: [CALC()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

css:

```
#someone_elses_div{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:70%;
}
#my_button{
    width:100px;
    margin-left:calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Was just going to say that absolute positioning doesn't require the parent element to have a position attribute, you beat me to it.

Comment: actually it wouldnt work, he needs the button positioned inside the div. i have updated my answer.

Comment: I replaced your margin-left line with float:right and that seems to work fine as well. Good answer either way.

Comment: This did not work on FF 24.5.0.  calc(100%) worked but not calc(100% - 100px)

Comment: according to that chart, FF24 has full calc compatibility, so probably the error lies elsewhere. note that vars and operator inside calc must be separated by a space. eg: `calc(100%-100px) not good` while `calc(100% - 100px) good`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but are you unable to change the parent's position due to not having access alone? If so, you could just use some jQuery to add the position.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#someone_elses_div').css({
          'position':'relative'
     });
});
```